# Insert user into database ANDROID APP

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to **insert a user login and password into a mysql database**

What i have so far is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
}

public void validateUser(View v) {
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    final String login_name = username.getText().toString();
    final String password_name = password.getText().toString();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website-name/insert.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", login_name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password_name));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        }).start();

    Intent homepageIntent = new Intent(signup.this, homepage.class);
    startActivity(homepageIntent);
    }
}
```

where in my xml file, the button when clicked executes validateUser. But when I run the emulator and create a user account , my program directs me to homepage but **doesn't add the user to the database**. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: `catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} catch (IOException e) {}` no, no, no.  Never "eat" an exception, especially when doing IO.  Step through with the debugger.  What happens?

Comment: Ok, so I put some Log.d inside the catch-es, so I don't "eat" any exceptions. 

When I run the program, I literally don't get any error. My logcat doesn't have an errors

Comment: Logcat is for logging, not for debugging.  Step through with the debugger.  Watch what happens.

Comment: Please don't tell me you're sending passwords unencrypted over the network...

Comment: @Simon: thanks for the tips. I read up on debugging and have been trying to debug the program for the last few hours. I think the problem is that "response" from the line **HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); ** returns null values and thus does not pass in the values for username and password from the app screen.

Comment: @NathanWalters: I am sending unencrypted passwords over the network, but I'm going to fix that once I get the functionality of adding users to the database working

Answer (score 0):

try to echo on `http://website-name/insert.php` and try to resolve the problem from there... Or try to write what you are sending into a file. If you can echo what you are sending on Server side or write into file, then is problem there.

But do not login into DB from client side.

Comment: I do have echo code in my php script that should echo either success or failure. It's not being executed at all though, which makes me think I am making the HTTP request wrong.

Comment: @getgoodatprogramming what do you get from ` HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();` ?

Comment: I get  **I/System.out﹕ Content-Type: text/html**
but when I run **response.getContent();** I get -1